# „Es besteht _kein_ Zweifel“ / „Es gibt _keinen_ Zweifel“ - why Nom. with bestehen?

Tags: verb, usage, nominative, objects

I'm trying to work out why Nom. is used in „Es besteht **kein** Zweifel“ but Akk. is used in „Es gibt **keinen** Zweifel“?

I would have expected things to be identical for *geben* and *bestehen*, i.e. *keinen Zweifel* for both.

I've googled and found various things, e.g. there are *Verben mit obligatorischem es* and for some the *es* is always Nom. and for some it can be either Nom. or Akk.:

- *Es [Nom.] fehlt ihm an Deutschkenntnissen.*
- *Ich versuche es [Akk.] mit Gitarrespielen.*

But this situation isn't about the *es* (it's Nom. in both situations):

- *Es [Nom.] besteht kein [Nom.] Zweifel.*
- *Es [Nom.] gibt keinen [Akk.] Zweifel.*

So can someone explain the grammar behind using *kein Zweifel* with *bestehen*?

Answer (score 6):

The *es* in the sentence "Es besteht kein Zweifel" is what is known as a dummy subject. According to *Hammer's German Grammar, 5e*: "*es* is often used as a 'dummy subject' in initial position in order to permit the 'real' subject to occur later in the sentence. This construction is particularly frequent if the 'real' subject is a noun phrase with an indefinite article or an indefinite quantifier. It gives more emphasis to the 'real' subject. *Es* may be used in this construction with any verb in German. The verb agrees with the 'real' subject, not with the *es*." (p.58) Some examples given in *Hammer's* (the 'dummy' subject is in bold):

> ***Es** waren viele Wolken am Himmel*. | **There** were many clouds in the sky.
> *Viele Wolken waren am Himmel.* | Many clouds were in the sky.

> ***Es** saß eine alte Frau am Fenster.* | **There** sat an old woman by the window. 
> *Eine alte Frau saß am Fenster.* | An old woman sat by the window.

> ***Es** liegen zwei Briefe für Sie auf dem Schreibtisch.* | **There** are two letters for you lying on the desk.
>  *Zwei Breife für Sie liegen auf dem Schreibtisch.* | Two letters for you are lying on the desk.

So, "Es besteht kein Zweifel" could theoretically be rephrased as "Kein Zweifel besteht", although the latter sounds unidiomatic to me as a main clause, i.e. I would sooner say and expect to hear

> "Es besteht kein Zweifel (daran), dass Deutsch eine schwierige Sprache ist."

than

> "Kein Zweifel besteht (daran), dass Deutsch eine schwierige Sprache ist."

although the second sentence does not sound awful to me (native speakers may have a different opinion).

In contrast, in the fixed phrase "es gibt", *es* is the 'real' subject of the verb *geben*, which is why this phrase in German is always "es **gibt**" (i.e. unless you use it in a compound construction such as with a modal verb, but then the modal would agree with *es*, e.g. *Hier soll es mehr Naturwald geben.*). Consequently, whatever "it gives" (read: "there is" or "there are") is the direct (accusative) object, e.g. *Es gibt kein**en** Zweifel*, *Es gibt ein**en** Fehler im Text*, etc.

**NB** that dummy subjects also exist in English (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/dummy-subjects), but the matter's less complicated because we don't have a prominent case system.

Comment: I don't think that it is good to call something that is not a subject a dummy subject.

Comment: Außerdem bestehen Zweifel *an etwas*. Keine Zweifel bestehen an der Richtigkeit dieser Aussage. Daher fehlt in Deinem Beispiel etwas: "Kein Zweifel besteht daran, dass Deutsch eine schwierige Sprache ist." Dann hört es sich auch gleich besser an.

Comment: I don't think he explanation with the "dummy subjective" (alias: [_expletive 'es'_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_expletive)) is good here, because this is not what differentiates the two sentences. To me, the whole point seems to be that _bestehen_ and _geben_ have different verb valence. I think [tofros answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/61271/15393) is much clearer here.

Comment: CarstenS's formulation with _daran_ feels much nicer.

Comment: I still find it hard to see the fundamental difference between _es besteht_ and _es gibt_ (despite the _real subject/dummy subject_ vs _standard subject_ explanation). I feel all the information is probably there in this answer and I just need to read it through a few times. I do have _Hammer's German Grammar_, so I'll take a look at it as well.

Comment: @CarstenS I think the use of "daran" is a matter of context and preference: [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r?from=&q=%22es+besteht+kein+Zweifel%22&h=1&corpus=kern).

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach OK, but I think that makes matters unduly abstract. The question is: Why, given that _es_ is nominative in both sentences, is the verb followed in one by the noun in the nominative and in the other by the noun in the accusative? Answer: It just is! But it helps to see that _es_ in one sentence has no semantic function (i.e. is a 'dummy', like "it" in "It is difficult to understand the difference."), while in the other it is the 'real' subject and the verb has a direct object. Invoking the concept of valency seems like a more abstract way of saying: "It just is that way!"

Answer (score 4):

The nominative is the "normal" thing - compare the English "there is no doubt".

The accusative in your second example is just the quirk in the German language that we express *existance* of something with "geben" - a transitive verb that wants (at least) an accusative object. (while English happily uses "is")

Replace "es gibt" with "es existiert" or "es besteht", which are both intransitive, and "Zweifel" falls back to nominative.

Also note the different usage of "es": With the transitive verb "geben" it is mandatory, with intransitives it's optional as long as we assure the verb is in second position:

- <s>Keinen Zweifel gibt</s>
- Kein Zweifel besteht
- Kein Zweifel existiert

Comment: What is the subject in "Es besteht kein Zweifel"? "es" or "kein Zweifel" ? Does "es" mean anything in that sentence?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Please see my response, below. I think this answers your question.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista *Es* is a pronoun that occupies the *Vorfeld* (i.e. satisfies the rule that the verb can only be in the second position). That's its only purpose.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'nominative is the "normal" thing' while accusative is a quirk. If asked for the most common simple sentence structure I'd give an example like _Ich gebe ihm den Ball_, i.e. Nom. Sub. - Verb - Dat. indirektes Obj - Akkusativ direktes Objekt. As a very common sentence form, I'd call this _normal_ and call a sentence featuring two Nom. Nomen _quite unusual_ - I'd previously thought this unique to _X ist Y_. So you mean something different to me by _normal_, could you provide a bit more detail? I need a little more help understanding your explanation.